# is it necessary to using accessors in friend function?

Tags: c++, friend-function

here is the class

```
class Instructor
{
 public:

Instructor ( int id , string name ) ;// constructor
 ~Instructor ()                       ;

// methods
string               getName           () ;
int                  getID             () ;



private:

int                  id             ;
string               name           ;

friend ostream & operator<< ( ostream & out , Instructor & instructor ) ;
 } ;
```

here is the ostream function

```
 ostream & operator<< ( ostream & out , Instructor & instructor )
{
out <<  "ID:" << instructor.getID() << "\t  NAME:" << instructor.getName() << "\t OFFERED_COURSES:" ;


return out << endl ;
```

}

and here is the getname and getID methods

```
  string Instructor::getName ()
{
  return this->name ;
}


int Instructor::getID ()
{
  return this->id ;
}
```

and my question is why do we need to use getID and getname functions. Can't we access to name  by writing "this->name" ? Thanks for answers.

Comment: I am concerned this question may turn into a flaming war about style issues. I am of the opinion that a friend acts as a fully-fledged member of the class it is a friend of.

Answer (score 4):

Necessary no, recommended yes.  In fact there's no need to declare `friend` at all, which is more encapsulated.

Comment: @user1559792 so that you can change the implementation affecting the least code as possible.

Comment: then you could say that member functions should also use the accessors so you don't have to change those either if you change the class representation.

friends should be treated like class members.

Comment: @CashCow If there's a reasonable chance that the implementation for the variable will change, why wouldn't you want to use the accessors to begin with to avoid having to change more code than necessary?

Comment: @CashCow: Indeed if a member function can be written so that it uses only accessors, it should be done so *and moved out of the class* (and into the enclosing namespace). Alternatively, it may be that your accessors are exposing too much of the class internals.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not so much "can't" as "shouldn't".   At this moment in time, `getID()` is just returning the underlying variable, but there's no guarantee that it won't change to a different representation.  Respect encapsulation when you encounter it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that (access private members directly in a friend function), but it is not the best way to do things.  Use the inspector functions because they should be written to expose the private state of the class *in the way that the class is written to have them used externally*.  The actual private fields are there for the class *to use itself to do what it needs to do internally*.

Because you are not using private members in your operator function, you don't even need it to be a friend.

Comment: I disagree, friends are part of the implementation, just like class members.

Comment: I counter-disagree :).  If the friend were truly tied to the implementation of the class, it would be an honest-to-goodness member of the class.

Comment: with streaming it can't be. You can of course provide a member "print" function that your stream calls (when print needs private access). 

And for classes that have a different lifetime you could use nested classes, but then you may as well say you never need friends.

Answer (score 0):

No, a friend is really an extended part of the implementation of your class, and therefore has direct access to it.

If you have declared a function or a class as a friend that is not part of its implementation detail, that is probably bad use of friend.

In your case, you can actually remove the streaming friend overload completely, however if you decided that your class would also support streaming in, and did not want to also support setter functions (or swap), you would be left with the only remaining option of having your stream-in as a friend writing directly to the member variables.

(Note that stream-in, if it fails, should leave the object in a default (newly constructed) state.

stream-out should be a friend when (and preferably only when) it needs to write to a stream members you would not normally provide direct access to.

Comment: "stream-in, if it fails, should leave the object in a default (newly constructed) state" - why's that then? Why not valid-but-unspecified? same-as-it-was-before-you-started would be even better, but not necessarily efficient. There's a particular problem that if the relevant flags are set on the stream, it might throw an exception when it fails -- to do as you say requires catching that exception, clearing the object and then rethrowing. Or of course clearing the object first, then doing the same-as-before-on-failure version of the stream-in operation.

Comment: @SteveJessop I remember reading that in C++11, int i=5; istr>>i; and the streaming fails, i should now be 0. I was also surprised but if that's the new standard, one should try to adhere to it. I would have thought the state should "unchanged" too.

Comment: hmm. `std::string` has an extractor that erases the string before it starts. There's example code in 22.4.8/9 that leaves a user-defined "Date" unmodified on failure, but that's an example of using a locale, not necessarily an example of best practice for extractors. Like you say, the arithmetic extractors appear to store zero on failure (22.4.2.1.2/3). It looks as though a "well-behaved" extractor shouldn't use other stream extractors, rather it should use locale "get" functions and set errors on the stream (perhaps throwing an exception) at the end.